# How to retrieve records missing in the group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve records using sql from the below dataset. For every combination of POKey and PAKey I am trying to find if there are RCode 9 and 10 are present and RCode 8 is missing.

I have attached the sample data, please help to give me a idea on how to do it.

[image]

Comment: And what happened to PoKay 456 ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select PoKey, PaKey, 'Missing 8'
from t
group by PoKey, PaKey
having sum(case when rcode = 9 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when rcode = 10 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when rcode = 8 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select distinct t.PoKey, t.PaKey, 'Missing 8' as Rcode
from table t
where RCode in (9, 10) and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.PoKey = t.PoKey and 
                        t1.PaKey = t.PaKey and 
                        t1.Rcode = 8
                 );
```